# getting html tags from xml and echoing in php?

Tags: php, html, xml

I am trying to echo a result from xml into my html code form expedia. But I ran into a problem. There text is a little messed up:

```
<areaInformation>
Distances are calculated in a straight line from the property&apos;s location to the point of interest or attraction, and may not reflect actual travel distance. &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt; Distances are displayed to the nearest 0.1 mile and kilometre. &lt;p&gt;La Isla Shopping Mall - 0.5 km / 0.3 mi &lt;br /&gt;Yamil Lu&apos;um - 0.5 km / 0.3 mi &lt;br /&gt;Acuario Interactivo - 0.6 km / 0.3 mi &lt;br /&gt;Luxury Avenue - 1.5 km / 0.9 mi &lt;br /&gt;Cancun Golf Club at Pok Ta Pok - 2.2 km / 1.3 mi &lt;br /&gt;Nautilus Diving and Training Center - 2.6 km / 1.6 mi &lt;br /&gt;Cancun Convention Center - 2.8 km / 1.7 mi &lt;br /&gt;Plaza Caracol - 2.8 km / 1.8 mi &lt;br /&gt;Playa Tortuga - 3.1 km / 1.9 mi &lt;br /&gt;Aquaworld - 3.6 km / 2.2 mi &lt;br /&gt;Playa Langosta - 4.1 km / 2.6 mi &lt;br /&gt;Museo de Arte Popular Mexicano - 4.6 km / 2.9 mi &lt;br /&gt;Playa Linda - 5 km / 3.1 mi &lt;br /&gt;Playa Delfines - 6.1 km / 3.8 mi &lt;br /&gt;El Rey Ruins - 6.2 km / 3.8 mi &lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;The preferred airport for ME Cancun - Complete ME All Inclusive is Cancun, Quintana Roo (CUN-Cancun Intl.) - 14.3 km / 8.9 mi. &lt;/p&gt;
</areaInformation>
```

And I echo it in php:

```
<div id="hotelInfo"><?php echo $areaInfo ?></div>
```

And of course I get this in the browser window:

```
Distances are calculated in a straight line from the property's location to the point of interest or attraction, and may not reflect actual travel distance. <br /><br /> Distances are displayed to the nearest 0.1 mile and kilometre. <p>La Isla Shopping Mall - 0.5 km / 0.3 mi <br />Yamil Lu'um - 0.5 km / 0.3 mi <br />Acuario Interac
```

etc.

How can I fix this??? Any help would be greatly apreciated! Thanks!
I want it to output normal text without any html tags.

Comment: Edit the XML file and use a <![CDATA[Distances are calculated in a straight line from the property's lo...]]

Comment: What's the exact problem? You give us the input and the bad output, ok, but give us also the **desired** output to help us understanding your needs.

Comment: I want it to output normal text without any html tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to decode the `htmlspecialchars` encoding found in that string:

```
<div id="hotelInfo"><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($areaInfo) ?></div>
```

See [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php).

Comment: You're welcome. If you also want to remove all of the HTML tags, you can run [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) *after* you have decoded the HTML specialchars. For all these basic functionality, PHP has useful functions already build-in.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to use a XSL transformation of the XML.

See http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php for details.

Comment: How to kill the fly with the rocket gun.

Comment: I looked at this and did not understand a thing. Do you think you could give me an example?

Comment: @WhitneySarahRogers As I said to Daniel, XSL transformations are a huge powerful complex tool. There's no need to learn and use such tool to solve your little formatting problem.

Comment: @lorenzo-s: XSL won't even work here as the string in question is not XML. So even it is powerful, it would not have any power here ;)